# Search combobox using active cell - VBA User form

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

i created an userform that works well, however there is an issue with the serach combobox i've created since it gets stuck when it finds a similar value that it's not exactly the one that should be searched, below some details:
The combobox search on a database column using the active cell untill it finds the matching value written by the user (search as you type),

here the code running when the userform is initialized to add all the values in the dropdown:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Cella As Range
    
    For Each Cella In Worksheets("Applicazioni").Range(Range("B9"), Range("B999999").End(xlUp))
    cboRicerca.AddItem Cella.value
    
    Next Cella
    
    End Sub
```

Below the code written to actually search

```
Private Sub cboRicerca_Click() 'cboRicerca is the name of the searchbox

Worksheets("Applicazioni").Range("B9").Select

Do Until ActiveCell = ""

If cboRicerca.value = ActiveCell.value Then

    Me.txtNome = ActiveCell.value
    cboAmbito = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value 'it's important that thanks to the search these 2 text boxes are automatically populated

    Exit Do
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
Loop

End Sub
```

The issue happens when the database is updated with a similar value, the search gets stuck on the first one found returning the wrong values in the 2 textboxes

eg. if i want to search the value "APPTEST" and there is another value "APPLICATION" standing before, the search get stuck on "APPLICATION"

Any idea on how it can be solved?

Comment: I don't see where you search for a value in the database ...

Comment: i edited the question with this part running when initializing the userform

Comment: `If cboRicerca.value = ActiveCell.value` is looking for an exact match - it will not match APPTEST with APPLICATION